# Using the SQL 'LIKE' statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I'm trying to pull some data from an SQL database based on what is entered into a text box. All of that is working, however I am having some trouble structuring the query like I want.

The query I have is this:

```
select emp.firstname, emp.lastname, emp.EmployeeNo, jc.Department

from EmployeeMaster emp

    inner join JobClass jc on emp.jobclass = jc.JobClass

where emp.firstname LIKE 'Joe P Smith' AND emp.lastname LIKE 'Joe P Smith'
```

The input coming from the webpage will be in the format of 'Joe P Smith' and this is something I don't have control of. In the database 'firstname' is stored as 'Joe P' and 'lastname' is 'Smith'. How would I need to change my query to return the correct data?

Comment: You can either break the name apart client-side into FirstName and Lastname and query the appropriate columns on the back-end with the substrings; or you can concatenate the columns on the back-end into a single column and search it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
MS SQL Server:
... where rtrim(emp.firstname) + ' ' + rtrim(emp.lastname) = string_being_passed

DB2, Oracle: 
... where trim(emp.firstname) || ' ' || trim(emp.lastname) = string_being_passed
```

But names are hard ("non-trivial"). To handle variations like "John P. Smith", you may need a commercial name matching product.

Note: Depending on the data, kind of column and how your database handles trailing spaces, you may not need the `trim` or `rtrim` (in doubt, leave them there). The true equivalent of `trim(str)` would be `ltrim(rtrim(str))` but `rtrim` will likely suffice, unless you need to worry about leading spaces in your database data.

Comment: The name will be exactly as it is from the database. It's being autocompleted from a list generated from all the names. The problem is I'm having to concatonate to get them to show up properly and there is little consistency. IE: Not all of them have a middle initial so breaking them up by white space doesn't always work.

Comment: Thanks. One question, when I tried to run it says that 'trim is not a recognized built in function name'

Comment: Try `rtrim()` instead. To be 100% the same, it would be `ltrim(rtrim( x ))`, but you probably only need the rtrim.

Comment: Trim is not a mssql command.  Use ltrim and rtrim to emulate trim

Comment: @theglauber Thanks, rtrim fixed that. What are the '||' doing and is there an mssql equivalent?

Comment: Cool. Depending on the kind of column and how your database treats trailing spaces, you may not need the `rtrim()`. In doubt, leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not a 100% perfect solution, but a compromise that works in most cases, and maybe you can live with that:

If you don't mind finding `Joe Smith` **and** `Joe P Smith` at the same time, you could just ignore the middle letters/names:
Use the blanks to split the user input, but use only the first and last word, and ignore the ones in the middle.

No matter if the user inputs `Joe Smith`, `Joe P Smith` or `Joe Jack John Smith`, you just use `Joe` and `Smith` and generate the following SQL:

```
where emp.firstname LIKE 'Joe%' AND emp.lastname LIKE '%Smith'
```

The caveat is that when `Joe Smith`, `Joe P Smith` **and** `Joe Jack John Smith` all actually exist in the database, the query would return all three.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the two columns.

```
Where firstname+' '+lastname like 'John smith'
```

Edit: if "John p" is not stored as firstname, only "John", then you have other problems.  You could falsely assume all names are one word and substring everything up to the first space, but then you eliminate names like "Mary Ann"

Comment: This doesn't help when the string being passed is `John P Smith`

Comment: `like` is not the correct operator for this; it is meant to be used with `%` and `_` wildcards.

Comment: You are correct. I just mimicked the syntax e had in his question. While slower, LIKE would return the same result